# How to set up ssh server with VPN tunnel? (Policy routing for sshd service)

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, routing, vpn

It's difficult to me to explain in words, so I made diagrams.

In short, I want this to work:
[image: The Goal]

Basically I want to be able to connect from my laptop [A] to my desktop [B] via ssh, and run terminal program over OpenVPN connection, let's say IRC client for example.

So far I have working sshd, OpenVPN tunnel, and port forwarding on my router, but seems like port is closed (or not being forwarded), I get connection timeout. <del>I also tried without VPN and that failed as well</del>.

> Edit:
>   When [B] runs without OpenVPN it accepts connections to External IP,
>   when it runs with OpenVPN it doesn't.

I have no idea what is wrong.

---

Strangely (for me) this is working ok:

[image]

I can connect from [A] to [B] `[A]$ ssh [B].local_IP`, 
and connect from [B](over VPN) to [B](WAN IP) `[B]$ ssh [B].WAN_IP`.
I hope this makes sense. In this configuration port forwarding seems to work, also sshd working locally; in previous configuration port forwarding is not working(?).

---

I thought it should be easy, but it's not. Searching google is futile.

<del>My router is Belkin F5D8636-4 v1 (01), potential candidate for causing trouble, but I would rather exclude every other possibility before buying new one.</del>

> Edit 2):
>  I stumbled upon [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66426/incoming-outgoing-seperation-for-vpn), but the answer doesn't work for me. After fiddling with policy routing I had some success, however it created some other problems, and I learned I have no comprehension of routing tables :(
> I believe however, the solution is in policy routing.

**Any advice appreciated.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I found answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55861/48402) (by coincidence).
This setup on the [B] machine solved the problem:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.X table 128
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.1.1
```

I guess credits to user [AGWA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27338/agwa).

Comment: nice graph in the op. thanks for the solution and references!!